# Difference between imaginary and complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

Recently I was talking to my teacher about complex and imaginary numbers and he told me basically that $i$ is a complex number; its real part is just 0. However, this has made me wonder; if you can see $i$ as a complex number because you could argue its real part is 0, how can you differentiate between complex numbers and imaginary numbers?

Comment: It should be added that in modern mathematics there is almost never any reason to talk about imaginary numbers in general -- just about everything you can say about imaginary numbers is just as valid about _all_ the complex numbers, so it is usually said in that more general form.

Comment: To add to the confusion, I've heard people call complex numbers in general "imaginary"...

Comment: The difference between a Complex Number and an Imaginary Number is a Real Number :D

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Every complex number can be written as $z=a+bi$, where $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ (real numbers). The number $a$ is called **real part of $z$** and the number $b$ is **the imaginary part of $z$**.

If the real part is zero then we call $z=bi$ as **pure imaginary** complex number.

Here is a diagram to show the inclusions:

[image]

Comment: So all imaginary numbers are complex numbers too? But couldn't you then argue that all real numbers are complex numbers with imaginary part 0?

Comment: Every real number is also a complex number since $\mathbb{R}\subset \mathbb{C}$, but they have a special property: their imaginary part is zero.

Comment: Wow, the real numbers are a subset of the complex numbers? I didn't know that, it all makes sense now.

Comment: @OmnipresentAbsence, see the image above.

Comment: Aren't $\pi + 3 i$, and probably $e + i \pi$, trancendent too?

Comment: isn't $0$ a pure imaginary number ?

Comment: @mercio, zero is a real number. Imaginary pure should be non real.

Comment: but the real part of $0$ is $0$, so as you say in your answer, $0$ is a purely imaginary number (and yes it is a real number too).  In fact it's the only real purely imaginary number.

Comment: @mercio, ok, my fault. I missed 'non zero $b$'.

Comment: Does anyone know of this source? Or a textbook with this sort of diagram?

Comment: @vonbrand yes they are, the diagram shows this: Any number that is not algebraic is transcendental (the two are mutually exclusive)

Comment: Thank you, the diagram is very informative. Is this diagram licensed by cc-by?

Comment: Wikipedia does not make a distinction between 'imaginary' and 'pure imaginary' in its tldr article on complex numbers. An imaginary number is a number of the form $a+bi$ where $b\neq 0$. There is a nice diagram of [this](https://www.shelovesmath.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Venn-Diagram-of-Numbers-768x445.png?ezimgfmt=ng:webp/ngcb23).

Comment: Oddly e^pi is an integer, -1, or in general, multiples of pi in this sort of exponent often gives integers. I suppose this is the root of why the so-called elliptical functions are so useful studying the integers and primes. (sorry, didn't know how to get a pi character here)

Comment: In your answer you don't explain what an imaginary number is. Instead, you explain what is pure imaginary, and you also explain what an imaginary part of a complex number is.

Answer (score 1):

Imaginary numbers are numbers than can be written as a real number multiplied by the imaginary unit $i$, and complex numbers are imaginary numbers, plus numbers that has both real and imaginary parts. $i$ is both imaginary and complex. The imaginaries are a subset of the complex numbers, as the naturals are a subset of the integers.

Comment: ... except for $0=0i$ which is not an imaginary number.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Mathematicians are professionals at finding these pathological examples... you're right :)

Comment: @HenningMakholm why wouldn't 0 be considered an imaginary number?